# Is it true that Hanbalis believe the Prophet will sit on Allah's throne?

Tags: aqidah

> ما قاله مجاهد من أن الله يُقعد محمدا صلى الله عليه وسلم على عرشه، قول
> غير مدفوع صحته، لا من جهة خبر ولا نظر
>
> ....what Mujahid said regarding Allah making Muhammad ﷺ sit on His
> Throne, the statement's authenticity can not be rejected, neither from
> a narrative standpoint nor from an observational standpoint...
>
> [Jami' al-Bayan, vol. 17, pg. 531](https://al-maktaba.org/book/43/9883)

If the narration is true, how can we negate any claims of anthropomorphism?

Comment: Anthropomorphism has to be negated from Allah, not from the prophet. Allah does not sit on the throne, not in the sense that a person sits. The Prophet being with Allah or being on His throne is a gesture of favor and is similar to Quranic verses such as in [66:11](https://quran.com/66:11?font=v1&translations=20) or the ascension beyond Sidrat al-Muntaha in Mi’raaj .

Comment: Ibn Taymiyyah did believe this (Majmu al Fatawa 4/374 & 5/391) but there is no proof of it from Quran/Sunnah... It is more like a metaphor for God's favor on him and infact, the Prophet() himself has made this crystal clear in the [Sahih Hadith](https://sunnah.com/urn/741560).

Comment: @Ghz, you are using taweel which was generally rejected by Atharis.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The statement that Allah (swt) will make the Prophet (pbuh) sit on His throne is not to be taken as true. It is quite simple to understand that it is neither in Allah's book nor an authentic narration from the Prophet (pbuh).

Comment: This seems to be main stream view among the Hanbalis so your answer is not factual.